# What am i doing wrong?

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, noise, continuous-signals, electrical-signal

How do I remove the noise (long vertical lines) from signal? I am applying AC voltage via function generator which is amplified by the power amplifier to a 6mm thick steel specimen. The signals are captured via AE sensor 60db preamplified to DAQ?[image]

3rd figure[image]